# How to have multiple observers to observable queue, but not read duplicate items from queue

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Say I have an observable queue class, like so:

```
function Queue(){

}

Queue.prototype.add = function(item){
     return (an Observable);
}

Queue.prototype.read = function(){
    return (an Observable);
}
```

everytime an item is added to the queue, ideally whoever called read would get the next new item.

So for example we have

```
const q = new Queue({some:data})

q.read().subscribe();  // stream of unique values
q.read().subscribe();  // stream of unique values
...
q.read().subscribe();  // stream of unique values
```

the Queue instance and read calls might be across separate Node.js process or in the same process, but in any case, I want to ensure that they do not read duplicate values from the queue, I want each read method to return a unique new item in the queue.

Is there a way to implement this with observables? I am pretty much totally new to using them.

Here is a naive and fairly incorrect implementation:

```
function Queue(){
  this.items = [];
  this.obsEnqueue = new Rx.Subject();
  this._add = function(item){
    this.items.push(item);
    this.obsEnqueue.onNext(item);
  }
}

Queue.prototype.add = function(item){
     this._add(item);
     // in real life this method will be async so we will return Observable
     return (an Observable);
}

Queue.prototype.read = function(){
    return this.obsEnqueue
       .filter(item => {
            return !item.isRead;
       })
       .map(item => {
           item.isRead = true;
           return item;
       });

}
```

Surely there is something wrong about the above code, but maybe you can understand what I am trying to do. With multiple callers to the read method, would like to have them each reading unread items.

I am marking them as read in the read method, but I am not sure if that boolean flag is making it's way to the original data source and if other read methods will see that.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly: Your goal is to ensure across multiple separate node-processes that certain objects are not "duplicates"(in a semantic meaning I'm guessing)? Or do you just want your queue not to return the same value twice on a `read()`-call? (Both would not be rxjs-related, but maybe you can clarify that by editing your question)

Comment: Could you rewrite your Queue class. It's very vague as to what's going on.

Comment: @olsn you are probably right, both not rxjs related

Comment: @Asti what's vague about the question?

Comment: I tried making it a little clearer